# GoogleMaps, "This app wont run unless you update Google Play services." On emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-api, google-play-services

I try to make Google Maps to work on my app.
But I don't have any Android-device so I use the Eclipse emulator.
I get the error message:

**"This app wont run unless you update Google Play services."** on the Emulator.

I use Google Play service revision 12, its what is said in Android SDK Manager, but how can I see what version I really use, even if it says revision 12?

Should the lib be on 2.2 API or not?
I try to make Google Maps to work from version 2.2 & above.
[image]

---

Same here, I want the target to be like 4.2.2 but should it be on API or not, cuz I use the google play services lib
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, there still is no support for Google Play Services, or Maps V2, on emulators.

Comment: you do not need to select `Google API's` as your tarket to use google play services. that is only for google maps v1

Comment: @ChrisBroadfoot: To create Virtual Device like the link will not make Google Maps to run on the emulator. I will try one more time and see if it will work, but after read other people, it seems to not work.

Comment: @tyczj: So the google play services dont need to point to the Google APIs? I can instead point to Android 2.2?

Comment: @DMT82 that is correct, google play service has nothing to do with Google API's